# Setting up laravel-oauth2 (facebook login), running into errors

Tags: oauth-2.0, laravel, laravel-4

I am trying to set up the oauth2 authentication system (for Facebook specifically) for Laravel 4 seen here: https://github.com/madewithlove/laravel-oauth2

I have a controller, Oauth2Controller.php, that controls this.  I am trying to include the the necessary files in the package into my controller.  Following the example for that repository, I use:

```
use OAuth2\OAuth2;
use OAuth2\Token_Access;
use OAuth2\Exception as OAuth2_Exception;
```

However, when I run the page, it is throwing an error for these lines.  Saying:

```
Symfony \ Component \ Debug \ Exception \ FatalErrorException
syntax error, unexpected 'as' (T_AS), expecting ',' or ';' or '{'
```

It references directly the third line: use OAuth2\Exception as OAuth2_Exception;

I am not sure why it is throwing this error.

Here is the full code of my controller:

```
<?php 

class Oauth2Controller extends BaseController
{

    use OAuth2\OAuth2;
    use OAuth2\Token_Access;
    use OAuth2\Exception as OAuth2_Exception;

    public function getIndex($provider) {


        $provider = OAuth2::provider($provider, array(
        'id' => '**************',
        'secret' => '******************',
        ));

        if(! isset($_GET['code'])) {

            return $provider->authorize();

        }

        else
    {
        // Howzit?
        try
        {
            $params = $provider->access($_GET['code']);

                $token = new Token_Access(array(
                    'access_token' => $params->access_token
                ));
                $user = $provider->get_user_info($token);

            // Here you should use this information to A) look for a user B) help a new user sign up with existing data.
            // If you store it all in a cookie and redirect to a registration page this is crazy-simple.
            echo "<pre>";
            var_dump($user);
        }

        catch (OAuth2_Exception $e)
        {
            show_error('That didnt work: '.$e);
        }
    }

    }


}
```

In my routes, to get to the page, I have:

```
Route::get('oauth/{provider}', 'Oauth2Controller@getIndex');
```

THank you for your help and insights!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have never seen a `use` clause (in this context, at least) within a controller's definitions.

Try placing the three clauses above `class`. Those need to import the namespaces for use in your class:

```
use <class>;
use <class> as {a_class}
...

class <name> ... {
```